# Why is my buck converter stimulation not working on proteus?

Tags: ground, buck, proteus

Why is my proteus stimulation only outputting the voltage and current zero when I connect the ground terminal - shown at the bottom right of the image, when I do not connect the ground terminal the output is 18V - which is way too high I am trying to achieve a 5v output[image]

Comment: Probably because op-amp controls VCC and Reset on 555, which drives the op-amp.  Evil circular control loop.

Comment: The buck circuit is not grounded, the feedback network is connected to the low side instead of high side, the amplifiers have no power, there's no current through D2 to set a voltage, etc.